# Mobx pause reactivity

Tags: mobx

Is something like this possible in Mobx?

```
const obj = { a: 1 };
makeAutoObservable(obj);

obj.pauseReactivity();
obj.a = 2 // no reactions
obj.resumeReactivity();
```

Comment: No, not really, you will need to do that in userland.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who looks for similar functionality, I made a package that enables this: https://github.com/lukigarazus/mobx-reaction-control